# MySQL update with and operator

Tags: java, mysql

I had written some wrong syntax for an SQL query. But still, it outputted no error with a java tomcat server. Running on Debian 9. 
MySQL Version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64)
```

The query was as follows, I had misplaced the comma ',' with 'and' after the set operator

```
UPDATE table_pod_print set print_status = 1 and operator_id = 2091 where id = 1
```

I tried running it on the console, which gave me the following output:

```
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Please help me in understanding why the query worked in the first place.

Comment: It is similar to when we mistakenly do `if(var = expression)`, instead `if(var == expression)`. MySQL would have been trying to evaluate `print_status = 1 and operator_id = 2091` as comparison instead of assignment, and got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL `SELECT 1 AND 0;` produces `0` because the [AND operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) evaluates operands as a logical AND. Looking at your query the `SET print_status` was evaluated as (adding additional brackets for clarity):

```
print_status = (1 AND (operator_id = 2091))
```

which mean it would be `1 AND 1` if `operator_id = 2091` for updated  `id = 1` row was true and `1 AND 0` if not.